# Incorrect exit code inside child script

Tags: linux, bash, exitstatus

I have a parent script, that execute a child script in background:

```
#!/bin/bash
# parent.sh
childScript $param1 $param2&
```

Child script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# childScript.sh
param1=$1
param2=$2
someLinuxCommand $param1 $param2
out=$?
echo $out
```

If I execute childScript.sh with correct $param1 and $param2, $? will return 0. If $param1 and $param2 are incorrect, $? will return 1.

But no matter what $param1 and $param2 I send using parent.sh, $? always return 0. Why if I send incorrect $param1 and $param2 from parent.sh, $? in childScript.sh return 0?

Comment: Make sure returncode of `someLinuxCommand` is correct and then remove `out=$?` and `echo $out`.

Comment: If I execute childScript.sh with correct $param1 and $param2, $? will return 0. If $param1 and $param2 are incorrect, $? will return 1.

Comment: Shouldn't even run, there shouldn't be spaces between assignments.

Comment: @123 Fixed question. I have no spaces in the code.

Comment: I forgot about one moment, childScript executed in background (childScript $param1 $param2&)

Answer (score 1):

In your child script you are "returning" the result of `echo` which will always be 0.  You should be using ...

```
exit $?
```

... instead. Or just leave that line out all together.

Here is an example that apes your scripts:

```
$ cat parent.sh
#!/bin/bash

p1=$1
p2='file'
./child.sh $p1 $p2

$ cat child.sh
#!/bin/sh

grep $1 $2
out=$?
echo $out
```

The child script will "grep" for the pattern in the "file".  Here are the contents of the file "file".

```
$ cat file
c.sh
file
in.txt
p.sh
bill
```

If grep find the pattern in the file grep will succeed thus setting $? to 0.  But if grep does not find the pattern in the file grep will fail this setting $? to 1.

Here we run parent with a pattern of "bob"

```
$ ./parent.sh bob
1
```

`grep` did not find bob in thus sets `$?` to 1. `echo` outputs 1 and then sets `$?` to 0.

```
$ echo $?
0
```

Let's fix the child.sh script to be:

```
$ cat child.sh
#!/bin/sh

grep $1 $2
```

and run parent.sh again:

```
$ ./parent.sh bob
$ echo $?
1

$ ./parent.sh bill
bill
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Same answer though. Your child scripts exit code is that of a successful execution of  `echo`.  Don't do the `echo $out`.  Exit code will be the exit code of `echo` which is not what you want.

Comment: >>> If I execute childScript.sh with correct $param1 and $param2, $? will return 0. If $param1 and $param2 are incorrect, $? will return 1. Problem happens when I execute childScript.sh from parent script.

Comment: Your scripts "return" an exit code which is set to errno of that last statement executed in the script.

Comment: last statement executed in the childScript.sh (someLinuxCommand $param1 $param2) is incorrect, but $out == 0.

Comment: No. That last statement executed in your child script is `echo` which succeeds thus setting `$?` to zero.

Comment: They aren't setting $? to the result of echo. The set it to the result of `someLinuxCommand $param1 $param2`...

Comment: I forgot about one moment, childScript executed in background (childScript $param1 $param2&)

Comment: @123 Yes the childscript is setting $? to the exit code of `echo $out` which would be zero.

Comment: They never echo the return of childscript though.

Comment: What does that even mean. "They never echo the return ..." The last line of the child script is `echo $out` is it not?

Comment: The last line of the child script is `echo $out` is it not? That set $? to 0. Doesn't that have the effect of the child script executing `exit 0` regardless of whether the someLinixCommand exited with error or not.